# Using symfony2 routing component (outside of symfony2)

Tags: symfony, routes, components, yaml

I've been searching and haven't really found much useful information. I'm looking to use the symfony2 routing component (and also yaml component) with my own personal framework but haven't found any documentation on basic setup. The documentation on the [symfony site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) does a good job of explaining how to use the component but not much in the way of standalone setup.

Can anyone recommend a good place to start that could explain how to setup individual symfony2 components?

Comment: good question! I am currently wondering about exactly the same!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up looking at the documentation on the [symfony site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), as well as the source code on github ([Route.php](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Route.php), [RouteCollection.php](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/RouteCollection.php), [RouteCompiler.php](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/RouteCompiler.php)) and came up with my own basic router.

Just like symfony, I allow 4 arguments to be passed to the route class -> 1) the pattern, 2) the default controller/action, 3) regex requirements for each variable in the pattern, and 4) any options - I haven't coded for this yet as it's not in my requirements.

My main/front controller (index.php) only talks to the static Router class which has access to the other route classes in the lib\route namespace.

Router::Map basically compiles a regex string (along with default controller/action and variable names) that gets passed to the compiledRouteCollection which is used in Router::_Process to match the httpRequest against.  From there, if there is a match in the process method then i set the controller/action/args based on the values of the matched compiledRoute default controller/action. If there is not a preg_match then i use the default controller/action/args from the request object. The rest is cake...

I hope someone finds this useful and it's able to save them the time I spent today working on this. Cheers!

index.php

```
require_once 'config/config.php';
require_once 'lib/autoload.php';
lib\Router::Map(
    'users_username_id',
    'users/{username}/{id}',
    array('controller' => 'testController', 'action' => 'users')
);
lib\Router::Route(new lib\Request());
```

router.php

```
namespace lib;

class Router {
protected static $_controller;
protected static $_action;
protected static $_args;
protected static $_compiledRouteCollection;
private static $_instance;

private function __construct() {
    self::$_compiledRouteCollection = new \lib\route\CompiledRouteCollection();
}

public static function Singleton() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        $className = __CLASS__;
        self::$_instance = new $className;
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public static function Route(Request $request, $resetProperties = false) {
    self::Singleton();

    self::_Process($request,$resetProperties);

    $className = '\\app\\controllers\\' . self::$_controller;
    if(class_exists($className, true)) {
        self::$_controller = new $className;

        if(is_callable(array(self::$_controller, self::$_action))) {
            if(!empty(self::$_args)) {
                call_user_func_array(array(self::$_controller, self::$_action), self::$_args);
            } else {
                call_user_func(array(self::$_controller, self::$_action));
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    self::Route(new \lib\Request('error'),true);
}

public static function Map($name, $pattern, array $defaults, array $requirements = array(), array $options = array()) {
    self::Singleton();
    $route = new \lib\route\Route($pattern,$defaults,$requirements,$options);
    $compiledRoute = $route->Compile();
    self::$_compiledRouteCollection->Add($name,$compiledRoute);
}

private static function _Process(Request $request, $resetProperties = false) {
    $routes = array();
    $routes = self::$_compiledRouteCollection->routes;
    foreach($routes as $route) {
        preg_match($route[0]['regex'], $request->GetRequest(), $matches);
        if(count($matches)) {
            array_shift($matches);
            $args = array();
            foreach($route[0]['variables'] as $variable) {
                $args[$variable] = array_shift($matches);
            }
            self::$_controller = (!isset(self::$_controller) || $resetProperties) ? $route[0]['defaults']['controller'] : self::$_controller;
            self::$_action = (!isset(self::$_action) || $resetProperties) ? $route[0]['defaults']['action'] : self::$_action;
            self::$_args = (!isset(self::$_args) || $resetProperties) ? $args : self::$_args;

            return;
        }
    }
    self::$_controller = (!isset(self::$_controller) || $resetProperties) ? $request->GetController() : self::$_controller;
    self::$_action = (!isset(self::$_action) || $resetProperties) ? $request->GetAction() : self::$_action;
    self::$_args = (!isset(self::$_args) || $resetProperties) ? $request->GetArgs() : self::$_args;
}
}
```

request.php

```
namespace lib;

class Request {
protected $_controller;
protected $_action;
protected $_args;
protected $_request;

public function __construct($urlPath = null) {
    $this->_request = $urlPath !== null ? $urlPath : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $parts = explode('/', $urlPath !== null ? $urlPath : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $parts = array_filter($parts);

    $this->_controller = (($c = array_shift($parts)) ? $c : 'index').'Controller';
    $this->_action = ($c = array_shift($parts)) ? $c : 'index';
    $this->_args = (isset($parts[0])) ? $parts : array();
}

public function GetRequest() {
    return $this->_request;
}

public function GetController() {
    return $this->_controller;
}

public function GetAction() {
    return $this->_action;
}

public function GetArgs() {
    return $this->_args;
}
}
```

route.php

```
namespace lib\route;

class Route {
private $_pattern;
private $_defaults;
private $_requirements;
public $_options;

public function __construct($pattern, array $defaults = array(), array $requirements = array(), array $options = array()) {
    $this->SetPattern($pattern);
    $this->SetDefaults($defaults);
    $this->SetRequirements($requirements);
    $this->SetOptions($options);
}

public function SetPattern($pattern) {
    $this->_pattern = trim($pattern);

    if($this->_pattern[0] !== '/' || empty($this->_pattern)) {
        $this->_pattern = '/'.$this->_pattern;
    }
}

public function GetPattern() {
    return $this->_pattern;
}

public function SetDefaults(array $defaults) {
    $this->_defaults = $defaults;
}

public function GetDefaults() {
    return $this->_defaults;
}

public function SetRequirements(array $requirements) {
    $this->_requirements = array();
    foreach($requirements as $key => $value) {
        $this->_requirements[$key] = $this->_SanitizeRequirement($key,$value);
    }
}

public function GetRequirements() {
    return $this->_requirements;
}

public function SetOptions(array $options) {
    $this->_options = array_merge(
        array('compiler_class' => 'lib\\route\\RouteCompiler'),
        $options
    );
}

public function GetOptions() {
    return $this->_options;
}

public function GetOption($name) {
    return isset($this->_options[$name]) ? $this->_options[$name] : null;
}

private function _SanitizeRequirement($key, $regex) {
    if($regex[0] == '^') {
        $regex = substr($regex, 1);
    }

    if(substr($regex, -1) == '$') {
        $regex = substr($regex,0,-1);
    }

    return $regex;
}

public function Compile() {
    $className = $this->GetOption('compiler_class');
    $routeCompiler = new $className;

    $compiledRoute = array();
    $compiledRoute = $routeCompiler->Compile($this);
    return $compiledRoute;
}
}
```

routeCompiler.php

```
namespace lib\route;

class RouteCompiler {

//'#\/tellme\/users\/[\w\d_]+\/[\w\d_]+#'
public function Compile(Route $route) {
    $pattern = $route->GetPattern();
    $requirements = $route->GetRequirements();
    $options = $route->GetOptions();
    $defaults = $route->GetDefaults();
    $len = strlen($pattern);
    $tokens = array();
    $variables = array();
    $pos = 0;
    $regex = '#';

    preg_match_all('#.\{([\w\d_]+)\}#', $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if(count($matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            if($text = substr($pattern, $pos, $match[0][1] - $pos)) {
                $regex .= str_replace('/', '\/', $text).'\/';
            }
            if($var = $match[1][0]) {
                if(isset($requirements[$var])) {
                    $regex .= '('.$requirements[$var].')\/';
                } else {
                    $regex .= '([\w\d_]+)\/';
                }
                $variables[] = $match[1][0];
            }
            $pos = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);

        }
        $regex = rtrim($regex,'\/').'#';
    } else {
        $regex .= str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern).'#';
    }

    $tokens[] = array(
        'regex' => $regex,
        'variables' => $variables,
        'defaults' => $defaults
    );
    return $tokens;
}
}
```

compiledRouteCollection.php

```
namespace lib\route;

class CompiledRouteCollection {
public $routes;

public function __construct() {
    $this->routes = array();
}

public function Add($name, array $route) {
    $this->routes[$name] = $route;
}
}
```

Comment: you don't use the symfony2 components. you just coded your own front-controller. great. but this is not what the question was about!?

Comment: @Raffael1984 I used the symfony 2 routing component as a basis for my routing. When I didn't get an answer I resolved to simplifying the symfony router to fit my needs. Seems like this was the answer, and if you look through the source code this will pretty much explain how it works and how to incorporate it in your framework once you understand it.

Comment: easy pal ... I feel with you ... the current doc on specific components is yet sub-par. BTW so far I figured out that you get very competent feedback on sf2-stuff on their IRC channel ... have look there.