# How to use the decoupled symfony components?

Tags: symfony, integration, modularity

Any information on how to use symfony's decoupled components?

I'm rereading the docs but there's nothing on the topic besides a general message of *"They are very very decoupled"* and 1 tutorial that [makes use of Request and Response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html#add-a-touch-of-symfony2).

There's also one badly ranked answer of [Using symfony2 routing component (outside of symfony2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718418/using-symfony2-routing-component-outside-of-symfony2)

Also having a look at a [tutorial for the standalone Form component](http://n.clavaud.free.fr/?31-symfony2-standalone-form-component-tutorial) doesn't actually excite me how pleasant this is.

I need the **routing**, **yaml**, and **session**.

Answer (score 7):

The first component you should use is **ClassLoader**. You can also use **spl_autoload_register**, but you're using Symfony, so why shouldn't you use its own autoloading library? Add the following at the top of the script:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

require_once '/path/to/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony' => '/path/to/symfony/src',
));
```

Using the **Yaml** component is really easy:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
$data = Parser::parse('yaml string');
```

For the other components, you'll have to read the [API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/), as there are no tutorials yet.

Comment: Actually a link to the API docs is not very helpful. The problem as I see is all components make use of at least 2 other components. So they are pretty much tied to them. 

The YAML component on its own is easy to decouple since sf1. I need YAML usage for routing configuration, not just YAML.

Comment: Looks like old version of Symfony is used in this example. It doesn't work and gives PHP error.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, Fabien Potencier just published a blog post which contains snippets of how to use the most common components. See the second half of [this post](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2) for details.

Comment: I've just [added a comment](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2#comments). I hope we can get some more standalone examples.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a tutorial which might help you, on using [decoupled Symfony components in your project](http://talater.com/symfony_console_component/).

It shows how to use the console component as an example, but the logic is the same for other components.

Answer (score 3):

Composer is the answer.

This video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOldVDVYnAE has a simple and straight forward step by step that answers your question.

**EDIT on august 26th 2020:** The video creator has made it private. Sorry, nothing I can do about it.

Comment: This is installation, not usage.

Comment: @antitoxic Watch it from 7:12 if you are not interested in the installation step. Although I strongly recommend you to watch the whole bunch.

Comment: this video is private :O

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony2 example**

1) Install the component You need with composer in new folder

```
composer require symfony/yaml
```

2) Create the script `yaml.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
$yaml = new Parser();
$value = $yaml->parse('invoice: 3484');
var_dump($value);
```

3) Run the script

```
php yaml.php
```